# Why does the Breeze/Knockout template install as a tool instead of a template making it unusable?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, javascript, javascript-framework, breeze

I am trying to use the Breeze/Knockout Template written by Ward Bell (AKA, BreezeJS MVC Template).  I successfully installed the breezetemplate.VSIX extension (by running the downloaded file) into VS 2012.

However, when I inspect the Extensions and Updates (from Tools in VS 2012) the Breeze Knockout Spa Template shows up under Tools not under Templates in the dialog.  I am assuming that is why when I create an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application, the Breeze Single Page Application does not appear in the next step when you are prompted to select a template to use.  It simply does not appear in the list of available templates to use.

I wanted to install this as a sample template to see a fleshed out usage of Breeze using EF and a data-repository on the back end.  I am using Hot Towel SPA as a starting point, but it really doesn't have any Breeze code.

I added in a simple Breeze DataContext to the Hot Towel Spa template based on the Breeze.WebApi NuGet packages written by Jay Traband.  Using that I was able to modify my project to use EF backed by a SQL database instead of a pseudo-database as used in the Breeze.WebApi example.

However, it looks like the Breeze/Knockout template written by Ward Bell is a more sophisticated example.  I need this more sophisticated sample to server as an example for how I want to use Breeze.

So after a long explanation here is what I am asking:

1) How can I get the Breeze/Knockout template to install as a template instead of as a tool in the VS 2012 Extensions and Updates?

2) If there isn't an answer to 1), is there somewhere where I download a VS 2012 project based on the Breeze/Knockout template?

3) If the answer to 2) is no, will Ward Bell please make a simple project based on this template available via GitHub, or other public code repository (NuGet Please!).

4) Is there some other non-trivial example of Breeze using EF and a data repository that is available to use as a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install  [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/02/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-update.aspx) to get the templates